# How to get Orange battery light back on Ubuntu?

Tags: battery

I have recently moved to Ubuntu from windows 10, and I’ve noticed that the orange battery light on my laptop that used to turn on when battery was low in windows doesn’t work in Ubuntu, ¿Is there anything I can do to make it return?

Comment: Details about make and model of your laptop would seem to be important here.

Comment: Lenovo Ideapad 320, I only want to get the orange light to turn on when low battery on Ubuntu

Comment: Interesting, I seem to have the same issue with an old Thinkpad T400s. Is the low battery light on when the laptop is running? On mine it only disappears when I put it in suspend, but not when it's running.